# Cannot understand the syntax inside Smarty foreach loop

Tags: php, smarty

In existing codebase, I found a line of

```
   {foreach from=$app_list item=app name=apps}
       {item table=application sid=$app.APPLICATION_SID}
   {/foreach}
```

I cannot find explanations to the line {item ... } in documentation, nor find where `application` and `sid` are defined.

Can anyone explain what this line is doing? Without this line, the list of app names cannot be displayed.

Comment: http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.foreach.tpl

Comment: `{item ...}` is a custom function. check [here](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.function.tpl)

Comment: @iJD Thanks for your answer. I read the documentation and think a function call is the only reasonable explanation. But the question is, I searched the whole project using `/function`, but cannot find the definition to this function, nor is the definition such like `var=application`. Is there other possibilities I should search?

Comment: try to find `item` `application`

Answer (score 0):

Check the code that calls this function. Most likely `application` and `$app` are being set there.

Answer (score 0):

It definitely looks like a custom function.  There are two possibilities:

1. There is a template that is being included which defines a custom function. Look for the string `{function item` or `{function name=item`
2. It could also be a smarty extension written in PHP.  Look for a file named `function.item.php`.  It could be in Smarty's `plugins` directory, or it might be somewhere in your source tree.  You might try looking at the setup code your project is using for Smarty, and see if the Smarty methods `setPluginsDir()` or `addPluginsDir()` methods are called.  If you are using an older version of Smarty, look for a reference to `->plugins_dir`.